# Afform and Contact Layout Editor for contact summary

Tags: contact-layout-editor, contact-summary-editor, formbuilder

We have been using Form Builder a lot lately to build reports for our teams. We recently saw that Form Builder integrates with Contact Layout Editor. If I use Form Builder to create a form with basic contact info and add it to Contact Summary, will it show the information from those fields or will it just be added to the Contact Summary page to collect data for those fields?

Essentially, we are looking for a good way to simplify the view on the Contact Summary page. We aren't sure if we will should that with Contact Layout Editor alone or if we need to also be using Afform/Form Builder.

Comment: have you read up about SearchKit, as i thought that was way to build a display of data that would potentially only show the data for the contact whose record you are looking at

Comment: https://www.thirdsectordesign.org/blog/using-and-contributing-to-searchkit has reference to blocks for Contact Summary screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found a solution that works for our needs. I created a List Display from SearchKit. Using Form Builder, I was able to use that List Display and create a new tab on the contact page. This gave us a new tab with only the information we wanted to to be available in a quick glance. SearchKit allowed us to set what could be edited in-place from that view.